# Equivalent of /dev/mqueue to enumerate SysV message queues

Tags: linux, system-v, sysv, mqueue

Linux supports two kinds of message queues: POSIX (i.e., those created by [`mq_open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_open.3.html)), and System V (i.e., those created by [`msgget`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgget.2.html)). For POSIX message queues, [`mq_overview(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html) documents that you can enumerate them via the `mqueue` virtual filesystem, usually mounted at `/dev/mqueue`. However, System V message queues don't show up there. How can I enumerate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `proc` virtual filesystem holds this information: `/proc/sysvipc/msg` is a file containing a list of all System V message queues. The [`ipcs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ipcs.1.html) program uses this file and shows you the same information, but in a more human-readable format.